# Ubuntu 15 vs Mint 17 vs Zorin 9 vs Elementary OS

Tags: windows, distribution-choice, distributions

I have always used windows but my computer is always overheating and i think i should try something new. I am going to clean it with compressed air and i am thinking of installing a linux distro as dual boot. What is the best option in terms of power, quickness, more software available and security?

I would like to run programs like matlab, java, arduino software, NI multisim, office, itunes...

Is there a way to while using linux open a program installed on the windows?

My pc as a hard drive divided by disk c, where the windows is instaled and a disk d almost empty. I think they are partitures of "a ata st9500325as"

Is it supposed to install in d???

Comment: I am voting for this question as opinion-based. I'm sorry, but your question **is** opinion-based - power, quickness and software available, as well as security depends mostly on your configuration. Also, these things are also debatable. The question formatted like this is not fit for Q&A site like StackExchange. However, you can search for help in Internet - there are many Linux forums where folks are glad to help, as well as people on IRC. Go reach them!

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner i would recommend using ubuntu 15, it is very similar to windows with it's interface and design, and has lots of resources available online for help. Most linux distros are anyways free, so you can try more than 1 if you wish (By using a bootable USB).

You can use java,arduino software, itnues and matlab on linux, It is also possible to use microsoft office on linux, but there are also diffrent office programs available ( Such as libreoffice), i'm not so sure about multiusm being on linux.

You can use wine to open some windows programs, although it can be buggy at times.

It is also possible to choose the partition which you want to install ubuntu on (Not so sure about zorin or elementary, but i'm sure you can on there too.).

Answer (score 1):

http://coteyr.net/articles/3-Moving-to-Open-Source

Fair warning it's my own site. But the core of the article (which is quite old), take it slow, make a complete list of what you use and try to migrate to it one at a time. Give your self time and expect a productivity drop.

As for running specific software, you will have to do your own research. Some software is for Linux only, some is cross platform (the vast majority of what runs on Linux is Open source and can run in Window, Mac, or other operating systems), and some has no Linux support at all.

For the stuff that has no Linux version, you can try CrossOver, Wine, PlayOnLinux or the like, but your usually best served by finding a replacement. There are usually replacements for most everything.  Some of the replacements are better, and some are not. You will have to decide.

If you install Crossover (maybe others) you *can* click on an exe and run it. That said, it usually won't work like that. You waill have to experiment and see.

As for how to install Linux you really need to read the install instruction for the distro you choose. You can put the install on /dev/sda (kinda like C:) or /dev/sdb (Kinda like D:) keep in mind that Linux deosn have drive letters just paths and mount points.  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html and http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop should get you started.  Just make sure to have a backup if you don't intend to replace windows.

As for speed, power, etc, Your on your own. That's way to much opinion. I dilike Unity, some love it. I like xfce some loath it. Mate is good, cinnamon is ok. Jump in and figure out what you like. That's one of the great things about Linux, you tailor it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just **went through a similar decision making process**. Distros are huge in number & variety. The packages vary like no tomorrow. The more you read, the more confused you will get.

**So, I figured I will start with a test install of Ubuntu as a stepping stone and then figure out which direction to go from there.**

I installed Ubuntu lts 12 and 14 but its Unity UI leaves much to be desired for someone who needs to find their Apps without knowing or remembering their names; especially for someone new to linux.

I'd much rather have a Menu like Windows that shows a bunch of Apps that are installed and in addition categorized.

Also, i like the silver / light gray/ mid gray look of of Windows 2000 Classic shell and the Apple osx minimal whitish/ grayish/ silver color.

Given these parameters, I finally chose Mint [also based on Ubuntu] as I liked their 2 main popular desktop environments - Cinnamon & MATE.

Now, I was faced with the issue of choosing between them with their Pros and cons on many articles, blogs and forums online.

I figured I want both to play with so figured I will download .iso for one of them and install the other after. I wasn't sure which order would be easier or better.

I looked at their .isos & tutorials [for both ways]  and figured its a bigger task to install Cinnamon than Mate.

So, I downloaded Mint Cinnamon 64 and will be adding MATE on it later and see how they both operate.

PS: Zori does claim to look similar to Windows, which caused me to look through it but found its colors a bit loud like the Windows XP, Vista, 7 world. I prefer a more muted, subtle look so for a clean looking interface I dropped Zori and went to Mint.